# Update Tanstack Query VueQueryPluginOptions

Tags: typescript, tanstackreact-query

I'd like to disable all my default requests and enable them after a particular request is made.
Here is my code in my main.ts file :

```js
const vueQueryPluginOptions: VueQueryPluginOptions = {
  queryClientConfig: {
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

app.use(VueQueryPlugin, vueQueryPluginOptions);
```

Here is my hook where I would like to update vueQueryPluginOptions and set enabled option to true :

```js
export function useScoopCheck() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    data: isScoopInstalled,
    error,
  } = useQuery(["check"], () => checkScoop(), {
    enabled: true,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      // Update VueQueryPluginOptions and set enabled to True
    },
  });

  return { isLoading, isScoopInstalled, error };
}
```